# Specified cast is not valid: numeric cell to int?

Tags: c#

Usually "specified cast is not valid" errors are easy to solve. But this one has gotten my head scratching.

I have a `SQL compact` database integrated in my `C#` application. At the moment I am getting the current database structure and putting it into a datatable. The SQL command im using is:

```
select * from information_schema.columns
```

One of the columns is `NUMERIC_PRECISION`, which is a numeric value.

I try and store this information in an integer variable, but it tells me the specified cast is not valid. The code is:

```
int precision;
if (row["NUMERIC_PRECISION"] != DBNull.Value)
    precision = (int)row["NUMERIC_PRECISION"];
```

My question is why is this operation invalid? The cell is a numeric value and I am trying to cast it to an integer - surely in theory this should work?

Comment: What's the type of `row["NUMERIC_PRECISION"]` when you inspect the value using the debugger?

Comment: Its a string. But it will always either be null or have a numeric value.

Comment: What you are getting in `row["NUMERIC_PRECISION"]`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you said that the value *could* be null, I would actually use a nullable integer to store it in.

```
int? precision = null;

if(row["NUMERIC_PRECISION"] != DBNull.Value) //or whatever you want to do to make sure it actually has a value
{
    //I usually use Convert.ToInt32 since its easier, but it is also more sensative
    precision = Convert.ToInt32(row["NUMERIC_PRECISION"]);
}
```

the `Convert` class is easy to use and visibly makes a lot of sense, its very sensitive to null or improperly formatted values though, and throws an exception when it finds one.

Comment: As a side note: Its never a good idea to try and cast to a string, every class inherits the `.ToString()` method from the `object` class itself, whenever you need a string, from anything, use that.  override it in your own classes if need be.

Answer (score 1):

row["NUMERIC_PRECISION"]  returns object that has an numberic typed boxed in it. You can cast it only to the exact type of this boxed object.

try casting to (decimal) or (long) first , and then to (int).

You can check the type of row["NUMERIC_PRECISION"] using debugger watch.

You can also ask Convert class to handle conversion for you:

```
precision = Convert.ToInt32(row["NUMERIC_PRECISION"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] Now you said it's a string: You must parse it.

Try: `precision = int.Parse((string)row["NUMERIC_PRECISION"]);`

That will throw an exception if it isn't in the correct format, so you must either be prepared to catch the exception, or use an overload of [int.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) to check its validity.

[EDIT2]

It seems that the data is not a string; it is an Int16. So do this:

`precision = (Int16)row["NUMERIC_PRECISION"];`

Comment: This solution returns the error: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int16' to type 'System.String'.`

Comment: In that case, you have NOT got a string in the row! See my edited reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try using int.parse instead of simple casting to int - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to: `int.Parse(string s)`

```
precision= Convert.ToInt32(row["NUMERIC_PRECISION"]);
```

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work in this scenario. `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int16' to type 'System.String'.`